# Обмен данными с ftp-сервером

Tags: ftp, файлы

Необходимо настроить автоматический обмен с заранее заданными файлами между FTP и локальным компьютером. Неважно как, главное, чтобы работало.
Пробовал через `FTPRush`, но не знаю, как написать сценарий.

Comment: ОСь на компьютерах какая? только Windows?

Comment: Да, только Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте написал скрипт на любом ЯП - python, php. Не важно, который бы используя консольный ftp клиент дергал бы с указанного ему ftp сервера файлы. Для python есть замечательная библиотека [ftplib — FTP protocol client](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html). Чтобы этот скрипт запускался сам - повешать его на виндовый планировщик задач.